# Using HandlerMethodArgumentResolver in requestMappingHandlerMapping

Tags: spring-mvc, request-mapping

```
 requestMappingHandlerMapping.registerMapping(requestMappingInfo, this, GenericController.class.getDeclaredMethod("handleRequests", UserData.class,
                    HttpSession.class, Locale.class, HttpServletRequest.class, Model.class));
```

where

```
 public void handleRequests(@ModelAttribute("userData") final UserData userData, final HttpSession session, final Locale local,
            final HttpServletRequest request, final Model model) throws Exception {
```

Is somehow possible to support @ModelAttribute injection?

Answer (score 0):

### The problem with your idea

Why would you want to use a `HandlerMethodArgumentResolver` in the `RequestMappingHandlerMapping`? The `HandlerMapping` is concerned with defining a mapping between requests and handler objects, not actually resolving the handler method arguments. That's what the `HandlerAdapter` is for.

`DispatcherServlet` provides the `RequestMappingHandlerAdapter` by default, with the `ModelAttributeMethodProcessor` as one of the `HandlerMethodArgumentResolvers`; this is the class that actually resolves `@ModelAttribute` - annotated arguments.

### A Suggestion

**Use `RequestMappingHandlerAdapter`. Why?**

- Separation of Concerns! Only this class should be concerned with resolving the arguments of the handler method, including `@ModelAttribute` parameters
- You're going to have to use this `HandlerAdapter` and its default `HandlerMethodArgumentResolver`s anyway to resolve the other arguments in your method (`HttpSession`, `Locale`, `Model`,...)